# В Yii2 не отрабатывает часть verbs в REST

Tags: yii2, rest

уважаемые гуру.

Есть следующий код:

```
<?php
namespace app\api\modules\v1\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats']['text/html'] = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        ];
        $behaviors['verbs'] = [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'index'  => ['GET'],
                'logout' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actionIndex(){
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return ['result'=>'fail', 'access_token'=>null];
        }else{
            return ['result'=>'success', 'access_token'=>'this-token'];
        }
    }
    public function actionCreate(){
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
        return ['action'=>'create', 'post'=>$post];
    }
    public function actionLogout(){
        $header = Yii::$app->request->headers;
        return $header;
    }
}
```

Исходя из вышесказанного: у меня есть два Action `'index' => ['GET']` и `'logout' => ['POST']`, если отправлять GET - все нормально.

Проблема заключается в том, что если идет POST то отрабатывает не `actionLogout()` а `actionCreate()`.

Как тогда мне в контроллере создать собственные Action и сделать адекватную их работу? Контроллер расширял именно от `yii\rest\Controller` ради того, чтобы прописать все вручную, а не использовать "то что дали" 

В `urlManager` не отправлять, поскольку из логики приложения, поведения проще прописать в контроллере, либо модуле.

Мой `'urlManager'`:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'cache'=>null,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => [
                    'v1/user',
                    'v1/auth',
                ],

                'pluralize' => false, //множественное число отключаем User->Users
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: покажите `urlManager`